# Mendeley - Exporting A Collection Straight to PDF or HTML

Tags: bibtex, citations

I'm in love with Mendeley Desktop for organizing my papers. I'm working on a survey paper and I want to send an updated list of the papers in the survey to my advisors. The best solution would be to get them to sign up for Mendeley, but they're not as techy as I am. Right now I'm doing the following:

1) export Mendeley to Bibtex
2) open Bibtex file in Jabref and export to HTML

Is there a way to cut out Jabref from this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glad that you love Mendeley Desktop :) The easiest way would probably be the following:

1) Select all your documents in Mendeley Desktop (CTRL+A or Edit > Select All)

2) Copy citation to clipboard (CTRL+C or Edit > Copy Citation)

3) Open a new Word document (e.g.)

4) Paste the clipboard (CTRL+V or Home > Paste in Word 2007).

Hope that helps! For further information you may also go to our forums at http://feedback.mendeley.com or contact us at support@mendeley.com.

Best wishes,

Sebastian